# Nested useContext Object not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, react-context

I'm creating a todo application with lists and list items like a Shopping list with items and a watch list with items etc.

This is a TypeScript application and this is my ContextProvider with an example list for reference and to see how my app's data should be.

```
const DUMMY_LIST: List[] = [
  {
    id: "12345",
    text: "Shopping List",
    items: [
      {
        id: "123456",
        text: "Shopping Item 1",
      },
      {
        id: "1234567",
        text: "Shopping Item 2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "123456",
    text: "Watch List",
    items: [
      {
        id: "123456",
        text: "Watch Item",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I use React Router, when I click a list element (shopping list) I render that list and add a new todo item to a selected list element. I get `list.id` with `useParams()` and find the list item, should modify it as a new item then `setLists()` with this new item but I can't do this last step.

```
const TodosContextProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = (props) => {
  const [lists, setLists] = useState<List[]>(DUMMY_LIST);

  const addTodoHandler = (todoText: string, listId: string) => {
    const newTodo = new Todo(todoText);

    const listItem = lists.find((list) => list.id === listId);
    //typescript does not let me go without those 
    const newItem = listItem?.items?.push(newTodo);
    //console.log(newItem);
    //console.log(lists);

    setLists(lists);
  };

  const addListHandler = (listText: string) => {
    const newList = new List(listText);

    setLists((prevLists) => {
      return prevLists.concat(newList);
    });
  };

  const contextValue: TodosContextObj = {
    //items: todos,
    lists: lists,
    addTodo: addTodoHandler,
    addList: addListHandler,
  };

  return (
    <TodosContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </TodosContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

When I add a new todo to existing dummy list elements I can see that it is added and the whole context is updated but when I create a new element I can't add a todo item to a newly created list element. The interesting thing is that `newItem` returns as a `number`. There is something wrong with my update function `addTodoHandler()` but I believe there is also something wrong with my List class.

```
class List {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  items: Todo[] | null;

  constructor(listText: string) {
    this.text = listText;
    this.id = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000));
    this.items = null;
  }
}
```

I am trying to tell TypeScript that items will be a Todo[] object but I have to create a new list element without any todo item obviously and set `items: Todo[] | null`. An update should be done when a new todo item is added.

The application initially did not have this list and items structure, It was just a simple todo list. I am trying to convert it into the said system but struggling to do so.

Any idea what I can do with this? How do I add a new todo item to list elements?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution I changed the data structure. Lists and Todos are now two separate lists and todos has a parent element now.

List.ts

```
class List {
  id: string;
  text: string;

  constructor(listText: string) {
    this.text = listText;
    this.id = Math.random().toString(24).substring(2, 7);
  }
}
```

Todo.ts

```
class Todo {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  parent: string;

  constructor(todoText: string, parent: string) {
    this.text = todoText;
    this.id = Math.random().toString(24).substring(2, 7);
    this.parent = parent;
  }
}
```

When I click a List element router creates a page with that list items id and I can create new todos this using this id (useParams) as parent property. Then I filter todo items according to parent element.

New challenge is to delete all todos with the same parent element when I delete a list element.